# Nested root integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, nested-radicals

The bigger goal is to find the antiderivative:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}~~~~~(*)$$

But I can settle for the definite integral in $(0,1)$. Motivation:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}=2\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}-\ln (1+2\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}})+C$$

This integral is easy to solve by using the following substitution:

$$x=u^4$$

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}=u\sqrt{1+u^2}$$

Now consider the integral $(*)$. If we take $x=u^8$, we get the integral:

$$(*)=\int \frac{8u^6du}{\sqrt{u^6+\sqrt{1+u^4}}}$$

Still seems bad, and Mathematica can't solve it (or the definite integral either).

Another way I tried is by the following substitutions:

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{y}{2}$$

$$(*)=\int \frac{y(\sqrt{1+y^2}-1)dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2} \sqrt{2+2y+y^2-2\sqrt{1+y^2}}}$$

$$y=\sinh t$$

> $$(*)=\int \frac{\sinh t(\cosh t-1)dt}{\sqrt{(\cosh t-1)^2+2\sinh t}}$$

Believe it or not, Mathematica actually solves this integral, but the resulting expression is so long and complicated, it seems useless (and by long I mean three times the size of my screen).

What do you think, is there a reasonable closed form solution for this integral? Or at least, the definite integral:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}=\int_0^{\sinh^{-1} \sqrt{8}} \frac{\sinh t(\cosh t-1)dt}{\sqrt{(\cosh t-1)^2+2\sinh t}}$$

---

**Edit:**

$$\int \frac{\sinh t(\cosh t-1)dt}{\sqrt{(\cosh t-1)^2+2\sinh t}}=\sqrt{(\cosh t-1)^2+2\sinh t}-\int \frac{\cosh t~dt}{\sqrt{(\cosh t-1)^2+2\sinh t}}$$

Now let's make another substitution:

$$e^t=v$$

> $$\int \frac{\cosh t~dt}{\sqrt{(\cosh t-1)^2+2\sinh t}}=\int \frac{(v^2+1)~dv}{v\sqrt{v-1}\sqrt{v^3+v^2+7v-1}}$$

Now I see the connection to elliptic integrals (which Mathematica gives as part of the answer).

We just probably need to factor:

$$v^3+v^2+7v-1$$

The limits $x \in (0,1)$ will become $v \in (1,3+\sqrt{8})$. We can also make another change of variable, leaving only one radical and getting somewhat better behaved function (finite everywhere on the real line):

$$z=\sqrt{v-1}$$

> $$\int \frac{(v^2+1)~dv}{v\sqrt{v-1}\sqrt{v^3+v^2+7v-1}}=2\int \frac{(z^4+2z^2+2)~dz}{(z^2+1)\sqrt{z^6+4z^4+12z^2+8}}=$$

$$=2\int \frac{dz}{(z^2+1)\sqrt{z^6+4z^4+12z^2+8}}+2\int \frac{(z^2+1)~dz}{\sqrt{z^6+4z^4+12z^2+8}}$$

Comment: @YuriyS I managed to convert it to $$\int \frac{\tan^3 x}{\sqrt{\sin^4 x+\sin x\cos^2 x}}$$ But IDK if this helps?

Comment: You are integrating $(dx)/y$ on a path in the algebraic curve $((y^2 - x)^2 - x)^2 = x$.  That does not look like genus 0.

Comment: @zyx, you mean antiderivative does not exist in terms of elementary functions, right? I understand it, Mathematica gives it in terms of incomplete elliptic integrals

Comment: There are rational differentials on the curve that have elementary integrals, but if the curve has positive genus, those are of measure 0 and there is no special reason to believe that $(dx)/y$ should be in that subspace. So it would be strong evidence that the problem has no elementary solution.  Probably mathematica is telling us indirectly that the genus is 1.

Comment: @zyx, my goal is to make the resulting expression as simple as possible. Mathematica can't solve the titular integral at all, but for the last one I derived it gives a reasonably sized solution. Maybe it can be further simplified

Comment: After some manipulation of the Taylor series expansion around x=2, I found another (probably unhelpful) result, that the antiderivative is equal to $\frac{\sqrt{π}}{k} \sum_{n=0}^{∞} [\frac{1}{(n+1)^2 \Gamma(\frac{1}{2} -n) \Gamma(n) \cdot k^{2n}}]\cdot (x-2)^{n+1}$ where $k=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$I'm just posting it here out of hope someone might obscurely recognize it.

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/500589/269624)

Comment: Seems we can write $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}= \int_0^1 \frac{2 x^{3/4}}{(1+x)^{1/4}\sqrt{\frac{1+x+x^{3/2}\sqrt{1+x}}{1+x}}} \; dx$

Comment: I think you've lost $z$ in the denominator in the last highlighted equation. The integrand should be $\frac{z^4+2 z^2+2}{\left(z^3+z\right) \sqrt{z^6+4 z^4+12 z^2+8}}$

Comment: @zyx could you give a reference to the genus and measure 0 claim you made? Preferably self-contained and no involving too much algebraic geometry. Thanks!

Comment: @YuriyS, I know how to solve this.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, that's great, are you going to post an answer?

Comment: @YuriyS, the answer will be posted tomorrow, after last checking. Crazy work and nice results.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, thank you, can't wait to see

Answer (score 22, accepted):

$$\color{brown}{\textbf{Simple example ($\mathrm{k=2}$).}}$$

Let us consider the integral
$$N_2(x) = \int \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}}.$$
Substitution
$$y = \sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt x}},\quad x=\dfrac1{(y^2-1)^2},\quad \mathrm dx = -\dfrac {4y}{(y^2-1)^3}\,\mathrm dy,\quad x>0,\quad y>1, \tag{i1}$$
gives
$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt x} = \sqrt{\dfrac1{(y^2-1)^2}+\dfrac1{y^2-1}} = \dfrac y{y^2-1},\tag{i2}$$
so
$$N_2(x)=Q_2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt x}}\right),\tag{i3}$$
where
$$Q_2(y) = -4\int\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{(y^2-1)^2} = \int\dfrac{-4+4y^2}{(y^2-1)^2}\,\mathrm dy - \int \dfrac{4y^2}{(y^2-1)^2}\mathrm dy$$
$$ =  4\int\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y^2-1} + 2\int y\,\mathrm d\left(\dfrac1{y^2-1}\right) 
= \dfrac{2y}{y^2-1}+ 2\int\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y^2-1},$$
$$Q_2(y) = \dfrac {2y}{y^2-1} + \log\left(\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right) + \mathrm{const}.\tag{i4}$$
Taking in account $(\mathrm{i2})$ and $(\mathrm{i4}),$ solution $(\mathrm{i3})$ can be written as
$$N_2(x) = 2\sqrt{x + \sqrt x} + \ln\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt x}}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt x}}+1}+\mathrm{const} = 2\sqrt{x + \sqrt x} + \ln\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}-\sqrt[4]x}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}+\sqrt[4]x}+\mathrm{const},$$
or, eliminating the numerator,
$$\boxed{N_2(x) = 2\sqrt{x + \sqrt x} - \ln\left(1 + 2\sqrt x + 2\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}\right) + \mathrm{const}}.$$

$$\color{brown}{\textbf{OP antiderivative ($\mathrm{k=3}$).}}$$

$\color{brown}{\underline{\textrm{Transformation to single radical.}}}$

**Substitution.**

Taking in account $(\mathrm i1)-(\mathrm i4),$ can be written
$$N_3(x) = \int \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt {x+\sqrt x}}} 
= Q_3\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt x}}\right),\tag{1}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
&\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}} = \sqrt{\dfrac1{(y^2-1)^2}+\dfrac y{y^2-1}},\\[4pt]
&Q_3(y) = \int\dfrac{-\dfrac {4y}{(y^2-1)^3}\,\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{\dfrac1{(y^2-1)^2}+\dfrac y{y^2-1}}}
 = \int\dfrac{-\dfrac {4y}{(y^2-1)^3}-\dfrac{y^2+1}{(y^2-1)^2}}{\sqrt{\dfrac1{(y^2-1)^2}+\dfrac y{y^2-1}}}\,\mathrm dy
 + \int\dfrac{\dfrac{y^2+1}{(y^2-1)^2}\,\mathrm dy }{\sqrt{\dfrac1{(y^2-1)^2}+\dfrac y{y^2-1}}}\\[4pt]
& = \sqrt{\dfrac1{(y^2-1)^2}+\dfrac y{y^2-1}}
+ \int \dfrac{y^2+1}{y^2-1} \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}.
\end{align}$$

Then
$$N_3(x) = 2\sqrt{x+\sqrt {x+\sqrt x}}
+Q_{30}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt x}}\right),\tag2$$
where
$$Q_{30}(y) = \int \dfrac{y^2+1}{y^2-1} \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}.\tag3$$

In this way, substitution $(\mathrm i1)$ has transformed given nested root integral to elliptic type.

**Algebraic transformations.**

Denote
$$\begin{cases}
P_3(y) = y^3-y+1\\[4pt]
r = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}} + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}}\approx 1.32471\,79572\,44746\\[4pt]
\lambda = \sqrt{3r^2-1} = \dfrac12\sqrt{4+\sqrt[3]{800+96\sqrt69}+\sqrt[3]{800-96\sqrt69}} \approx 2.06509\,87866\,78274\\[4pt]
w = \dfrac12+\dfrac34\dfrac r\lambda\approx 0.98110\,94143\,9836556,\\[4pt]
p = r+\lambda \approx 3.38981\,67439\,23020.
\end{cases}\tag4$$

Then
\begin{align}
&P_3(-r)=-\left(\dfrac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}+\dfrac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}\right)
-3\left(\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}} \cdot \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}}\right)\\
&\times\left(\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}} + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}}\right)
+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}} + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}}+1\\
&=-3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{12}{324}}\left(\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}} + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}}\right)+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}} 
+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}}=0,
\end{align}
i.e. $(-r)$ is the root of $P_3(y),$
$$r^3=r+1\tag5.$$

According to the Bezou theorem, $P_3(y)$ allows the decomposition in the form of
$$P_3(y) = y^3-y+1 = (y+r)(y^2-ry+r^2-1) = (y+r)\big((y+r)^2-3r(y+r)+3r^2-1\big),$$
or
$$P_3(y) = (y+r)\big((y+r)^2-3r(y+r)+\lambda^2).\tag6$$

On the other hand, for any constant $p$ can be obtained the fractional decomposition of
$$R_3(y) = \dfrac{y^2+1}{y^2-1} = A + B\dfrac{y+p}{y-1} + C\dfrac{y+p}{y+1},$$
where
$$B = \lim\limits_{y\to1}\dfrac{y-1}{y+p}R_3(y) = \dfrac1{p+1},$$
$$C = \lim\limits_{y\to-1}\dfrac{y+1}{y+p}R_3(y) = -\dfrac1{p-1},$$
$$A = \lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\left(R_3(y)-B\dfrac{y+p}{y-1} - C\dfrac{y+p}{y+1}\right)
 = \dfrac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}.$$

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
&Q_{30}(y) = \dfrac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}I_0(y) + \dfrac1{p+1}I_1(y,p+1) - \dfrac1{p-1} I_1(y,p-1),\tag7\\[4pt]
&\text{where}\\[4pt]
&\begin{cases}
I_0(y) = \int\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}\\
I_1(y,q) = \int\dfrac{y+p}{y+p-q}\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}\\
\end{cases}\tag8
\end{align}$$

$\color{brown}{\underline{\textrm{The first elliptic integral.}}}$

Substitution $(\mathrm i1)$ transforms the interval $x\in(0,1)$ to the interval $y\in(\infty,\sqrt2).$ Should be found the real-valued antiderivative for this interval.

Substitution
$$y=g(t) = -r+\lambda\tan^2t,\quad 
\mathrm dy = 2\lambda\dfrac{\tan t}{\cos^2t}\,\mathrm dt,
\quad t=\arctan\sqrt{\dfrac{y+r}\lambda}\tag{f1}$$

for the presentation $(6)$ gives
\begin{align}
&I_0(g(t)) = \int\dfrac{2\lambda\dfrac{\tan t}{\cos^2t}}{\sqrt{\lambda\tan^2t\left(\lambda^2\tan^4t
-3r\lambda\tan^2t+\lambda^2\right)}}\mathrm dt\\[4pt]
&=\int\dfrac{2\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{\lambda(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)^2-(2\lambda+3r)\sin^2t\cos^2t}}\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt \lambda}\int \dfrac{\mathrm d(2t)}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2\lambda+3r}{4\lambda}\sin^2 2t}}
= \dfrac1{\sqrt \lambda}\mathrm F(2t\ |\ w)+\mathrm{const},
\end{align}

where

> $$\quad F(\varphi\ |\ w) = \int\limits_0^\varphi \dfrac{\mathrm d\varphi}{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2\varphi}}\tag{f3}$$
>   is the [elliptic integral of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html).

Assuming the domain of $x\in(0,\infty)$ and taking in account $(\mathrm f1),$ one can get
$$\left(y\in(1,\infty)\right)\wedge(y+r\in(\lambda,\infty)) \Rightarrow
t\in\left(\dfrac\pi4,\dfrac\pi2\right),$$
$$\sin^2 2t = \dfrac{4\tan^2 t}{(1+\tan^2 t)^2},$$
then
$$\sin^2 2t = \sin^2(\pi-2t) = \dfrac{4\lambda(y+r)}{(y+r+\lambda)^2},\quad 
\cos 2t = -\cos(\pi-2t) = \dfrac{\lambda - y - r}{\lambda+y+r}\tag{f4}$$
$$\pi - 2t = 2\arctan\sqrt{\dfrac\lambda{y+r}}
= \arccos\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}.\tag{f5}$$

At the same time,

> $$\mathrm F(\pi-\varphi\ |\ w) = \mathrm F\left(\dfrac\pi2\ \bigg|\ w\right)
>  - \mathrm F(\varphi\ |\ w).\tag{f6}$$

Therefore,
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{\dfrac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}I_0(y) 
= -\dfrac1{\sqrt \lambda}\dfrac{(\lambda+r)^2+1}{(\lambda+r)^2-1}
F\left(\arccos\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}\ \Bigg|\ w\right) + const. \tag{f7}}}$$

Note that the choice $\mathrm{const}=0$ provides the condition $I_0(\infty)= 0.$

> Substitution $(\mathrm f1)$ effectively transforms the expression under the radical and provides simple form of solution for $I_0(y)$.
>   Effective integration of $I_1(y,q)$ looks more serious problem. Decomposition in the form $(7),(8)$ for choosen value $(4)$ of parameter $p$ allows to simplify integration.

$\color{brown}{\underline{\textrm{The second elliptic integral.}}}$

From $(4),(8)$ should
$$I_1(y,q) = \int\dfrac{y+r+\lambda}{y+r+\lambda-q}\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}.\tag{s1}$$

Applying substitution $(\mathrm f1)$ and taking in account $(4),$ one can get
\begin{align}
&I_1(g(t),q)=\int \dfrac{\lambda(1+\tan^2 t)}{\lambda(1+\tan^2 t) -q}\cdot
\dfrac{2\mathrm dt}{\sqrt \lambda\sqrt{1-w\sin^2 2t}} 
=\int \dfrac1{\lambda-q\cos^2 t}\cdot
\dfrac{\mathrm 2\sqrt \lambda\,\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2 2t}}\\[4pt]
&= \int \dfrac1{2\lambda-q-q\cos 2t}\cdot
\dfrac{4\sqrt \lambda\,\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2 2t}}
= \int \dfrac{2\lambda-q+q\cos 2t}{(2\lambda-q)^2-q^2\cos^2 2t}\cdot
\dfrac{4\sqrt \lambda\,\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2 2t}}\\[4pt]
&= -\int \dfrac{2\lambda-q+q\cos 2t}{4\lambda(q-\lambda)-q^2\sin^2 2t}\cdot
\dfrac{4\sqrt \lambda\,\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2 2t}}\\[4pt]
&= -\int \dfrac{2\lambda-q-q\cos(\pi-2t)}{4\lambda(q-\lambda)-q^2\sin^2(\pi-2t)}\cdot
\dfrac{4\sqrt \lambda\,\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2(\pi-2t)}}\\[4pt]
&= \int \dfrac{\dfrac{2\lambda-q}{2\sqrt \lambda(q-\lambda)}
-\dfrac{q\cos(\pi-2t)}{2\sqrt \lambda(q-\lambda)}}
{1-\dfrac{q^2}{4\lambda(q-\lambda)}\sin^2(\pi-2t)}\cdot
\dfrac{\mathrm d(\pi-2t)}{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2(\pi-2t)}},
\end{align}
$$\begin{align}
&\mathbf{\dfrac1q I_1(g(t),q)= A(q)\Pi\left(u(q),\pi-2t\ |\ w \right)
 -B(q)P\left(u(q),\pi-2t\ |\ w \right) + const},
\end{align}\tag{s2}$$

where
$$\begin{cases}
A(\lambda+r\pm1)=\dfrac1{2\sqrt\lambda}\dfrac{1\pm(r-\lambda)}{(r\pm1)(\lambda+r\pm1)}
\approx \dbinom{0.00885\,15573\,11770}{-0.78032\,04227\,56824}\\[4pt]
B(\lambda+r\pm1) = \dfrac1{2\sqrt\lambda(r\pm1)}\approx\dbinom{0.14966\,81250\,93454}{1.07150\,27311\,21398}\\[4pt]
u(\lambda+r\pm1)=\dfrac{(\lambda+r\pm1)^2}{4\lambda(r\pm1)}\approx\dbinom{1.00350\,99620\,67355}{2.12922\,75171\,98979},
\end{cases}\tag{s3}$$

> $$\Pi(u,\varphi\ |\ w) = \int\limits_0^\varphi \dfrac{\mathrm d\varphi}{(1-u\sin^2\varphi)\sqrt{1-w\sin^2\varphi}}\tag{s4}$$
>   is the [elliptic integral of the third kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheThirdKind.html), and
>   $$\mathrm P(u,\varphi\ |\ w) = \int\limits_0^\varphi \dfrac{\cos\varphi\,\mathrm d\varphi}{(1-u\sin^2\varphi)\sqrt{1-w\sin^2\varphi}}
> =\dfrac1{2\sqrt{u-w}}\ln\left|\dfrac{\sqrt{u-w}+\sqrt{\csc^2\varphi-w}} {\sqrt{u-w}-\sqrt{\csc^2\varphi-w}}\right|\tag{s5}$$
>   (see also [Wolfram Alpha test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdt%20(ln(sqrt(u-w)%2Bsqrt(csc%5E2%20t-w))%20-%20ln(sqrt(u-w)-sqrt(csc%5E2%20t-w))))) can be considered as "pseudo-elliptic" integral, linked with known rational integral in the form of
>   $$\int \dfrac{\mathrm ds}{(as^2+b)\sqrt{fs^2+g}}= 
> {\small \begin{cases}
> \dfrac 1{\sqrt{b(ag-bf)}}\arctan \dfrac{s\sqrt{ag-bf}}{\sqrt{b(fs^2+g)}},\quad\text{if}\quad ag-bf > 0\\[4pt]
> \dfrac1{2\sqrt{b(bf-ag)}}\ln \left|\dfrac{\sqrt{b(fs^2+g)}+s\sqrt{bf-ag}}{\sqrt{b(fs^2+g)}-s\sqrt{bf-ag}}\right|
> \quad\text{if}\quad ag-bf < 0.
> \end{cases}}\tag{s6}
> $$

$\color{brown}{\underline{\textrm{Transformations of the second integral solution.}}}$

**Solving of the convergency problem.**

From $(4),(\mathrm s3)$ should $w < 1 < u(q),$ and the first inequality provides real-valued final expression of $(\mathrm s3)$.

On the other hand, the second inequality presents hyperbolic case of $\Pi-$function. This leads to the convergency problem, because the denominator equals to zero if $u(q)\sin^2(\pi-2t) = 1.$

Taking in account $(\mathrm f4)$ and $(\mathrm s3),$ one can get
\begin{align}
&u(p+1)\sin^2(\pi-2t) = \dfrac{y+r}{(\lambda+y+r)^2}\left(\dfrac{1+r}{(\lambda+1+r)^2}\right)^{-1}\in(0,1),\\[4pt]
&u(p-1)\sin^2(\pi-2t) =\dfrac{y+r}{(\lambda+y+r)^2}\left(\dfrac{r-1}{(\lambda+r-1)^2}\right)^{-1}\in(0,3.897),
\end{align}
$$u(p+1)\sin^2(\pi-2t)\bigg|_{y=1}=1,\tag{t1}$$
$$u(p-1)\sin^2(\pi-2t)\bigg|_{y=\dfrac{2r^2+r-1}{r+1}\approx 11.8} = 1.\tag{t2}$$

To avoid this problem, the integral $(\mathrm s2)$ should be transformed.

Let
$$u(q)v(q)=w,\quad b=\sqrt{(u(q)-1)(1-v(q))},\tag{t3}$$

then
$$\dfrac1{1-u\sin^2 \varphi}+\dfrac1{1-v\sin^2\varphi}
= 1+\dfrac{1-w\sin^4\varphi}{1-(u+v)\sin^2\varphi+w\sin^4\varphi},$$
\begin{align}
&\dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\varphi}\left(\ln\left(\sqrt{1-w\sin^2 \varphi}+b\tan\varphi\right) 
- \ln\left(\sqrt{1-w\sin^2\varphi}-b\tan\varphi\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac{2b(w\sin^2\varphi\tan^2\varphi-\sec^2\varphi)}{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2\varphi}(b^2\tan^2\varphi+w\sin^2\varphi-1)}\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac{2b(1-w\sin^4\varphi)}{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2\varphi}
(-b^2\sin^2\varphi+(1-w\sin^2\varphi)(1-\sin^2\varphi))}\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac{2b(1-w\sin^4\varphi)}
{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2\varphi}(1-(b^2+w+1)\sin^2\varphi+w\sin^4\varphi)}\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac{2b(1-w\sin^4\varphi)}
{\sqrt{1-w\sin^2\varphi}(1-(u+v)\sin^2\varphi+w\sin^4\varphi)}.
\end{align}

So
$$\mathbf{\mathrm \Pi(u(q),\varphi,w) = \dfrac1{2b}\ln
\dfrac{\sqrt{\csc^2\varphi-w}\cos\varphi+b}{\sqrt{\csc^2\varphi-w}\cos\varphi-b}
+\mathrm F(\varphi,w) - \mathrm \Pi(v(q),\varphi,w),\tag{t4}}$$
wherein
$$v(\lambda+r\pm1) = \dfrac{(3r+2\lambda)(r\pm1)}{(\lambda+r\pm1)^2}\approx\dbinom{0.97767\,78023\,97853}{0.46078\,18593\,70775}.\tag{t5}$$

**Simplifications.**

Firstly, the factor near $\mathrm F(\varphi,w)$ is
\begin{align}
&-\dfrac1{\sqrt\lambda}\dfrac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}+A(p+1) - A(p-1)\\[4pt]
&= -\dfrac1{\sqrt \lambda((\lambda+r)^2-1)}\bigg((\lambda+r)^2+1+\dfrac{(\lambda+r-1)(r-\lambda+1)}{2(r+1)}+\dfrac{(\lambda+r+1)(\lambda-r+1)}{2(r-1)}\bigg)\\[4pt]
&= -\dfrac1{\sqrt \lambda((\lambda+r)^2-1)}\bigg((\lambda+r)^2+1+\dfrac{(r^2-(\lambda-1)^2)(r-1)+((\lambda+1)^2-r^2)(r+1)}{2(r^2-1)}\bigg)\\[4pt]
&= -\dfrac1{\sqrt \lambda((\lambda+r)^2-1)}\bigg((\lambda+r)^2+1
+\dfrac{-r^2+2\lambda r+\lambda^2+1}{r^2-1}\bigg)\\[4pt]
&= -\dfrac1{\sqrt\lambda((\lambda+r)^2-1)}\bigg((\lambda+r)^2-1
+\dfrac{r^2+2\lambda r+\lambda^2-1}{r^2-1}\bigg)\\[4pt]
&= -\dfrac1{\sqrt\lambda((\lambda+r)^2-1)}((\lambda+r)^2-1+r((r+\lambda)^2-1))
= -\dfrac{r+1}{\sqrt\lambda}.
\end{align}

At the second, applying formulas $(\mathrm f4),(\mathrm s3),(\mathrm t1),(\mathrm t5),$ one can get:
$$\begin{cases}
u(p\pm1)-1 = \dfrac{(r\pm1+\lambda)^2}{4\lambda(r\pm1)}-1 
= \dfrac{(r\pm1-\lambda)^2}{4\lambda(r\pm1)},\\[4pt]
1-v(p\pm1) = \dfrac{u(p\pm1)-w}{u(p\pm1)}
=\dfrac1{(r\pm1)(\lambda+r\pm1)^2},\\[4pt]
b = \sqrt{(u-1)(1-v)} = \dfrac1{2\sqrt\lambda(r\pm1)}\dfrac{1\pm(r-\lambda)} {\lambda+r\pm1} = A(q),
\end{cases}\tag{t6}$$
so the factor near the logarithm in formulas $(\mathrm t4)$ is $\frac12.$

Besides,
\begin{align}
&\csc^2(\pi-2t) - w = \dfrac{(y+r+\lambda)^2}{4\lambda(y+r)}-\dfrac12 - \dfrac{3r}{4\lambda} = \dfrac{(y+r)^2 + \lambda^2-3r(y+r)}{4\lambda(y+r)} = \dfrac{y^3-y+1}{4\lambda(y+r)^2},
\end{align}

then
$$2\sqrt\lambda\sqrt{\csc^2\varphi-w}\cos\varphi
= \dfrac{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}{y+r}\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}
= \sqrt{y^3-y+1}\left(\dfrac2{y+r+\lambda}-\dfrac1{y+r}\right).\tag{t7}$$

At last,
\begin{align}
&u(p\pm1)-w 
= \dfrac{(\lambda+r\pm1)^2}{4\lambda(r\pm1)}-\dfrac12-\dfrac{3r}{4\lambda}\\[4pt]
&= \dfrac{3r^2-1+2\lambda(r\pm1)+(r\pm1)^2-2\lambda(r\pm1)-3r(r\pm1)}{4\lambda(r\pm1)}
=\dfrac{r^2\mp r}{4\lambda(r\pm1)}
=\dfrac{r^3-r}{4\lambda(r\pm1)^2},\\[4pt]
\end{align}
$$\begin{cases}
u(p\pm1)-w = \dfrac1{4\lambda(r\pm1)^2}\\[4pt]
\sqrt{\dfrac{\csc^2(\pi-2t) - w}{u(p\pm1)-w}} = \dfrac{y\pm1}{y+r}\sqrt{y^2-y+1}\\[4pt]
\dfrac{B(p\pm1)}{2\sqrt{u(p\pm1)-w}} 
=\dfrac12\dfrac{2\sqrt \lambda(r\pm1)}{2\sqrt \lambda(r\pm1)} = \dfrac12,\\[4pt]
\end{cases}\tag{t8}$$

so
$$\mathbf{B(p\pm1)\mathrm P\left(u(p\pm1),\arccos\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}\ \Big|\ w \right) = \dfrac12\ln\left|\ \dfrac
{y+r + (r\pm1)\sqrt{y^3-y+1\phantom{\Big|}}}
{y+r - (r\pm1)\sqrt{y^3-y+1\phantom{\Big|}}}\ \right|. \tag{t9}}$$

**Closed form of the antiderivative.**

Finally, the closed form of antiderivative can be presented by the formula $(2),$ where
$$\color{green}{\boxed{\mathbf{\begin{align}
&Q_{30}(\infty)-Q_{30}(y) = \dfrac{r+1}{\sqrt\lambda}
\mathrm F\left(\arccos\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}\ \Bigg|\ w\right)\\[4pt]
&+\dfrac12\ln\left|\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}{y+r}\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}+C_1}
{\dfrac{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}{y+r}\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}-C_1}\right|
+\dfrac12\ln\left|\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}{y+r}\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}+C_2}
{\dfrac{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}{y+r}\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}-C_2}\right|\\[4pt]
&-\dfrac{C_1}{2\sqrt\lambda}\Pi\left(\dfrac{(3r+2\lambda)(r+1)}{(\lambda+r+1)^2},\arccos\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}\ \Bigg|\ w \right)\\[4pt]
&-\dfrac{C_2}{2\sqrt\lambda}\Pi\left(\dfrac{(3r+2\lambda)(r-1)}{(\lambda+r-1)^2},
\arccos\dfrac{y+r-\lambda}{y+r+\lambda}\ \Bigg|\ w \right)\\[4pt]
& +\dfrac12\ln\left|
\dfrac {y + r + (r+1)\sqrt{y^3-y+1\phantom{\Big|}}}
{y + r - (r+1)\sqrt{y^3-y+1\phantom{\Big|}}}\right|
-\dfrac12\ln\left|\dfrac {y + r + (r-1)\sqrt{y^3-y+1\phantom{\Big|}}}
{y + r - (r-1)\sqrt{y^3-y+1\phantom{\Big|}}}\right|,\\[4pt]
&C_1 = \dfrac{r-\lambda+1}{(r+1)(r+\lambda+1)},\quad 
C_2 = \dfrac{\lambda-r+1}{(r-1)(r+\lambda-1)},
\end{align}}}\tag{*}}$$
wherein the parameters $r,\,\lambda,\,w$ are given by $(4),$ and $Q_{30}(\infty) = 0.$

Since 
\begin{align}
&\int_{\sqrt2}^\infty \dfrac {y^2+1}{y^2-1} \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{y^3-y+1}}
=Q_{30}(\infty) - Q_{30}(\sqrt2)
\end{align}
$\approx4.01502\,83666\,96210\,78140$ ([term1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(r%2B1)%2Fsqrt%20l%20(EllipticF(arccos(1-(2l)%2F(sqrt2%2Br%2Bl)),(2%2B3r%2Fl)%2F4)),where%20r%3D(cbrt(108%2B12sqrt69)%2Bcbrt(108-12sqrt69))%2F6,l%3Dsqrt(3r%5E2-1)))
$+0.33133\,29488\,62457\,95551$ ([term2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=.5ln%7C(s%2B2%2F(1%2Br%2Bsqrt(3r%5E2-1))-1%2F(1%2Br))%2F(s-2%2F(1%2Br%2Bsqrt(3r%5E2-1))%2B1%2F(1%2Br))%7C-0.3313329488624579555112,where%20r%3D(cbrt(108%2B12sqrt69)%2Bcbrt(108-12sqrt69))%2F6,s%3Dsqrt(1%2Bsqrt2)(2%2F(sqrt2%2Br%2Bsqrt(3r%5E2-1))-1%2F(sqrt2%2Br))))

$+0.03549\,45749\,48612\,01694$ ([term3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=.5ln%7C(s%2B1%2F(r-1)-2%2F(r-1%2Bsqrt(3r%5E2-1)))%2F(s-1%2F(r-1)%2B2%2F(r-1%2Bsqrt(3r%5E2-1)))%7C-.03549457494861201693889,where%20r%3D(cbrt(108%2B12sqrt69)%2Bcbrt(108-12sqrt69))%2F6,s%3Dsqrt(1%2Bsqrt2)(2%2F(sqrt2%2Br%2Bsqrt(3r%5E2-1))-1%2F(sqrt2%2Br))))
$-0.13827\,66191\,08129\,76996$ ([term4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F(1%2Br%2Bl)-1%2F(2%2B2r))EllipticPi(((3r%2B2l)(r%2B1))%2F(r%2Bl%2B1)%5E2,arccos(1-(2l)%2F(sqrt2.%2Br%2Bl)),(2%2B3r%2Fl)%2F4)%2Fsqrt%20l-.13827661910812976996%20,where%20r%3D(cbrt(108%2B12sqrt69)%2Bcbrt(108-12sqrt69))%2F6,l%3Dsqrt(3r%5E2-1)))

$-2.80594\,91779\,29332\,44409$ ([term5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F(2r-2)-1%2F(r-1%2Bl))EllipticPi(((3r%2B2l)(r-1))%2F(r%2Bl-1)%5E2,arccos(1-(2l)%2F(sqrt2.%2Br%2Bl)),(2%2B3r%2Fl)%2F4)%2Fsqrt%20l-2.805949177929332444089%20,where%20r%3D(cbrt(108%2B12sqrt69)%2Bcbrt(108-12sqrt69))%2F6,l%3Dsqrt(3r%5E2-1)))
$+0.80579\,17865\,34765\,72804$ ([term6+term7](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(ln%7C(y%2Br%2B(r%2B1)sqrt(y%5E3-y%2B1))%2F(y%2Br-(r%2B1)sqrt(y%5E3-y%2B1))%7C-ln%7C((y%2Br%2B(r-1)sqrt(y%5E3-y%2B1))%2F(y%2Br-(r-1)sqrt(y%5E3-y%2B1)))%7C)%2F2,where%20r%3Dcbrt(1%2F2%2Bsqrt69%2F18)%2Bcbrt(1%2F2-sqrt69%2F18),%20y%3Dsqrt2))

$\approx 2.24342\,18800\,04584\,26784,$

then
$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}}}
= 2\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}-(Q_{30}(\infty)-Q_{30}(\sqrt2)) \approx 0.86412\,60680\,55497.$$

This result corresponds with the numeric calculations

[image: Numeric calculations of the issue integral]

and confirms the obtained formulas for the antiderivative.

Comment: Thank you for your work and the clever substitution idea. I'll give you a little bounty in 24 hours :)

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Great work. Impressive and instructive derivation. (+1)

Comment: @YuriyS Once more [interesting substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578605/integral-int-0-infty-frac-ln-left-sqrtx1-vphantomx0-1-right-ln-lef/3489521#3489521)

Comment: @YuriyS [Curious integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705505/how-can-i-find-i-n-int-01-frac-x2n-ln-x1-x21x4ndx/3778181#3778181)