# Compute $\sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m - 1} \left(c_j + 1\right)\ln\left(c_j + 1\right)$ where $c_j = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2m}\left(1 + 2j\right) \right)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, logarithms, trigonometric-series

As part of solving:

\begin{equation}
 I_m = \int_0^1 \ln\left(1 + x^{2m}\right)\:dx.
\end{equation}
where $m \in \mathbb{N}$. I found an unresolved component that I'm unsure how to start:

\begin{equation} 
 G_m = \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} \left(c_j + 1\right)\ln\left(c_j + 1\right),
\end{equation}

where $c_j = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2m}\left(1 + 2j\right) \right)$

I'm just looking for a starting point. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

By the way, I was able to show (and this was part of the solution too) :

\begin{equation}
 \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} c_j = 0
\end{equation}

Edit: For those that may be interested. In collaboration with [clathratus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/583016/clathratus), we found that for $n > 1$

\begin{equation}
    \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t^n + 1}\:dt = \frac{1}{n}\left[\frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n} \right)}- B\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n},  \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]
\end{equation}

Or for any positive upper bound $x$:
\begin{align}
 I_n(x) &= \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{t^n + 1}\:dt = \frac{1}{n}\left[\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)- B\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n},  \frac{1}{x^n + 1}\right)\right]
\end{align}

Here though, I was curious to investigate when $n$ was an even integer. This is my work:

Here we will consider $r = 2m$ where $m \in \mathbb{N}$. In doing so, we observe that the roots of the function are $m$ pairs of complex roots $(z, c(z))$ where $c(z)$ is the conjugate of $z$. To verify this:

\begin{align}
 x^{2m} + 1 = 0 \rightarrow x^{2m} = e^{\pi i}
\end{align}

By [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers), we observe that:

\begin{align}
 x = \exp\left({\frac{\pi + 2\pi j}{2m} i} \right) \mbox{ for } j = 0\dots 2m - 1,
\end{align}

which we can express as the set

\begin{align}
 S &= \Bigg\{  \exp\left({\frac{\pi + 2\pi \cdot 0}{2m} i} \right) , \:\exp\left({\frac{\pi + 2\pi \cdot 1}{2m} i} \right),\dots,\:\exp\left({\frac{\pi + 2\pi \cdot (2m - 2)}{2m} i} \right)\\
&\qquad\:\exp\left({\frac{\pi + 2\pi \cdot (2m - 1)}{2m} i} \right)\Bigg\},
\end{align}

which can be expressed as the set of $2$-tuples

\begin{align}
 S &= \left\{ \left( \exp\left({\frac{\pi + 2\pi j}{2m} i} \right) , \:\exp\left({\frac{\pi + 2\pi(2m - 1 - j )}{2m} i} \right)\right)\: \bigg|\: j = 0 \dots m - 1\right\}\\
& = \left\{ (z_j, c\left(z_j\right)\:|\: j = 0 \dots m - 1 \right\}
\end{align}

From here, we can factor $x^{2m} + 1$ into the form

\begin{align}
x^{2m} + 1 &= \prod_{r \in S} \left(x + r_j\right)\left(x + c(r_j)\right) \\
 &= \prod_{i = 0}^{m - 1} \left(x^2 + \left(r_j + c(r_j)\right)x + r_j c(r_j)\right) \\
 &= \prod_{i = 0}^{m - 1}  \left(x^2 + 2\Re\left(r_j\right)x + \left|r_j \right|^2\right)
\end{align}

For our case here $\left|r_j \right|^2 = 1$ and $\Re\left(r_j\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi + 2\pi j}{2m} \right)= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2m}\left(1 + 2j\right)\right) = c_j$

\begin{align}
    \int_0^1 \log\left( x^{2m} + 1\right)\:dx &=  \int_0^1 \log\left(\prod_{r \in S} \left(x^2 + 2c_jx+ \left|r_j \right|^2\right)\right)\\
    &= \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} \int_0^1 \log\left(x^2 + 2c_jx + 1 \right)\\
    &= \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} \left[2\sqrt{1 - c_j^2}\arctan\left(\frac{x + c_j}{\sqrt{1 - c_j^2}}\right) + \left(x + c_j\right)\log\left(x^2 + 2c_jx + 1\right) - 2x \right]_0^1 \\
    &= \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} \left[ 2\sqrt{1 - c_j^2}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 - c_j}{1 + c_j}} \right) + \log(2)c_j + \left(\log(2) - 2\right) + \left(c_j + 1\right)\log\left(c_j + 1\right) \right] \\
    &= 2\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}\sqrt{1 - c_j^2}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 - c_j}{1 + c_j}} \right) + \log(2)\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} c_j + m\left(\log(2) - 2\right)\\
    &\qquad+ \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}\left(c_j + 1\right)\log\left(c_j + 1\right)
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \log\left( x^{2m} + 1\right)\:dx &=\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}c_j\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2m}\left(1 + 2j\right)\right)  + \log(2)\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} c_j + m\left(\log(2) - 2\right)\\
&\qquad+ \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}\left(c_j + 1\right)\log\left(c_j + 1\right)
\end{align}

Comment: @Mason - Yes, thanks for the pickup, I will edit now

Comment: And $G_n$ should be $G_m$? Sorry. I don't have a lot to add to this question except catching pedantic typos... [Here's](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1qqolilsow) the closed forms for $I_0,I_1,I_2$. Does $I_m$ have a nice closed form? And is it easy to see how $I_m$ and $G_m$ are connected?

Comment: @Mason - Yes, sorry, I'm not on my game at the moment. I will correct. Thanks for the pickup. Have been trying to find the relationship through brute force examination (at present) and haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: I do not know in which context you worked $I_m$. This is problem I faced years ago and there is a nice closed form  for it.

Comment: Would you like me to post @ClaudeLeibovici?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Do you want to add to your post or do you want me to post the result for $I_m$ (this would be off-topic with regard to the question). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - I will edit my post. If it's different from your solution, please post up.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out David ;) I'll try to answer the question

Comment: @clathratus - Thank you for posting the question and your work on it. I've been fascinated with the question since your initial solution (the same that Claude) came to.

Comment: Have a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.02094.pdf

Comment: $\arctan\sqrt{\dfrac{1-c_j}{1+c_j}}=\dfrac{2j+1}{4m}\pi.$

Comment: I have finished calculalions given here. Closed forms both the sum and the integral have been obtaned and checked. Waiting for the comments about my answer..

Answer (score 6):

*This does not answer the question as asked in the post.*

Consider
$$J_m=\int \log(1+x^{2m})\,dx$$ One integration by parts gives
$$J_m=x \log \left(1+x^{2 m}\right)-2m\int \frac{ x^{2 m}+1-1}{x^{2 m}+1}\,dx=x \log \left(1+x^{2 m}\right)-2mx+2m\int \frac{dx}{x^{2 m}+1}$$ and
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^{2 m}+1}=x \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2 m};1+\frac{1}{2 m};-x^{2 m}\right)$$ where appears  the Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function.

So 
$$K_m=\int_0^a \log(1+x^{2m})\,dx=a \log \left(1+a^{2 m}\right)-2ma+2ma \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2 m};1+\frac{1}{2 m};-a^{2 m}\right)$$ and, if $a=1$,
$$I_m=\int_0^1 \log(1+x^{2m})\,dx= \log \left(2\right)-2m+2m \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2 m};1+\frac{1}{2 m};-1\right)$$ which can write
$$I_m=\log (2)-\Phi \left(-1,1,1+\frac{1}{2 m}\right)$$
where appears  the Lerch transcendent function.

Now, (this is something I never looked at), a few (ugly) expressions for $f_m=\Phi \left(-1,1,1+\frac{1}{2 m}\right)$ **before** any simplification
$$f(1)=\frac{\pi }{2}-2$$
$$f(2)=\frac{1}{4} \left(\pi  \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+\pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)-4 \sqrt{2} \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)\right)+4
   \sqrt{2} \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)\right)\right)-4$$
$$f(3)=\frac{2 \left(\pi -\sqrt{3} \log \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)+\sqrt{3} \log
   \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)
   \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)}-6$$
$$f(4)=\frac{1}{4} \left(\pi  \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)+\pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi
   }{16}\right)-8 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{3
   \pi }{16}\right)\right)+8 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log \left(\cos
   \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)-8 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log
   \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{16}\right)\right)+8 \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right) \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{16}\right)\right)\right)-8$$

Comment: Yes, my collaborator and I came to the same result (very nice closed form indeed). If I may ask - what are your thoughts on the special case I've discussed?

Comment: @DavidG. Your post is very interesting. I need to spend more time with it !

Comment: Please do! I look forward to any comments you may have. Thanks again for your post.

Comment: Mathematica calculates the same result

Answer (score 4):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Preliminary notes.}}$

> Calculation of the required sum looks more complex task than of the
>   issue integral.
>
> Approach with calculations of the sum via the inttegral allows to get close form both of the integral and the sum.

Denote
$$I_n=\int\limits_0^1\log(1+x^n)\mathrm dx.\tag1$$
Easy to see that the issue integral is $I_{2m}.$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Closed form of the integrals.}}$

The first step is the integration by parts:
$$I_n = x\log(1+x^n)\biggr|_0^1-n\int_0^1x\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n}\mathrm dx,$$
$$I_n = \log2 - n + n\int\limits_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^n}.\tag2$$
(see also [Claude Leibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053596/compute-sum-limits-j-0m-1-leftc-j-1-right-ln-leftc-j-1-right/3053718#3053718)).

Then, the substitution 
$$x=e^{-t}\tag3$$
gives
$$J_n=\int\limits_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^n}=\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-t}\,\mathrm dt}{1+e^{-nt}} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-(kn+1)t}\,\mathrm dt=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k}{kn+1} ,$$
$$J_n = \int\limits_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^n}= \dfrac1{2n}\left(\psi_0\left(\dfrac{n+1}{2n}\right) - \psi_0\left(\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)\right),\tag4$$
where $\psi_0(x)$ is the [polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html).

Using $(2),(4),$ easy to get the expression for the OP integral in the form of
$$\boxed{I_{2m} = \log2 - 2m +\dfrac1{2}\left(\psi_0\left(\dfrac{2m+1}{4m}\right) - \psi_0\left(\dfrac{1}{4m}\right)\right).}\tag5$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Testing of the solution.}}$

Solution $(4)$ can be expressed via the elementary functions for a lot of [the given values of n](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20%7B(polygamma(0,%201%2F2%20%2B%201%2F(2%20n))%20-%20polygamma(0,%201%2F(2%20n)))%2F(2%20n)%7D,%20%7Bn,9%7D).

Immediate calculations allow to check obtained expressions in the simple cases
\begin{align}
&J_1 = \int\limits_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x} = \log 2,\\[4pt] 
&J_2 = \int\limits_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2} = \arctan 1 = \dfrac\pi4,\\[4pt]
&J_3 = \int\limits_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^3} 
= \dfrac16\int\limits_0^1\left(\dfrac{2}{1+x} - \dfrac{2x-1}{1-x+x^2} + \dfrac{3}{1-x+x^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \left(\dfrac13\log(1+x) - \dfrac16 \log(1-x+x^2) + \dfrac1{\sqrt3}\arctan\dfrac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}\right)\bigg|_0^1
= \dfrac\pi{3\sqrt3} + \frac13 \log2.\\[4pt]
\end{align}
More hard cases are
\begin{align}
&J_4 = \int\limits_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^4} 
= \dfrac{\sqrt2}8\left(\log\dfrac{x^2 + \sqrt2 x + 1}{x^2 - \sqrt2 x + 1} 
- 2\arctan(1-\sqrt2x) + 2\arctan(\sqrt2x+1)\right)\bigg|_0^1\\[4pt]
&= \dfrac{\sqrt2}8\left(\log\dfrac{(x^2 + \sqrt2 x + 1)^2}{1+x^4} + 2\arctan\dfrac{x\sqrt2}{1-x^2}\right)\bigg|_0^1
= \dfrac{\sqrt2}8(\pi+\log(3+2\sqrt2)),\\[4pt]
&J_4=\dfrac18\Bigg(\dfrac12\sqrt{\dfrac{2-\sqrt2}{2+\sqrt2}}\pi+\dfrac12\sqrt{\dfrac{2+\sqrt2}{2-\sqrt2}}\pi
-2\sqrt2\left(-\log2+\dfrac12\log(2-\sqrt2)\right)\\[4pt]
&+2\sqrt2\left(-\log2+\dfrac12\log(2+\sqrt2)\right)\Bigg)\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac18\Bigg(\dfrac\pi2\left(\tan\dfrac\pi8+\cot\dfrac\pi8\right)
+\sqrt2\log\dfrac{2+\sqrt2}{2-\sqrt2}\Bigg)
 = \dfrac{\sqrt2}8(\pi+\log(3+2\sqrt2)),
\end{align}
and $n>4.$

Numeric calculations [of the issue integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20ln(1.%2Bx%5E%7B2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16%7D)dx) $I_{2m}$ and [its closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bln2-%7B2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16%7D%2B(polygamma(0,%201%2F2%20%2B%201%2F(2%7B2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16%7D))%20-%20polygamma(0,%201%2F(2%7B2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16%7D)))%2F2.%7D) $(5)$ also confirm the correctness of the closed form.

$\color{brown}{\textbf{The alternative approach.}}$

The alternative approach is considered in OP. Let us repeat it with some differences.

Polynomial factorization can be presented in the form of

\begin{align}
&1+x^{2m} = \prod\limits_{j=0}^{2m-1}{\large \left(x-e^{\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi i}\right)}
 = \prod\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}\left(x^2-2x\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi+1\right),
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
&I_{2m} = \int\limits_0^1 \ln(1+x^{2m})\,\mathrm dx
 = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1} T_j,\quad\text{where}\\[4pt]
&T_j = \int\limits_0^1 \ln\left(x^2-2x\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi+1\right)\,\mathrm dx,\\[4pt]
&T_j = x\ln\left(x^2-2x\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi+1\right)\bigg|_0^1
 - 2\int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{x\left(x-\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right)}{x^2-2x\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi+1}\,\mathrm dx\\[4pt]
& = \ln\left(2-2\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right)
 - 2-2\int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{x\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi-1}{x^2-2x\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi+1}\,\mathrm dx\\[4pt]
& = \ln\left(2-2\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right) - 2
 - 2\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi \int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{x-\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}{x^2-2x\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi+1}\,\mathrm dx\\[4pt]
& + 2\int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{\sin^2\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}{\left(x-\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right)^2+\sin^2\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}\,\mathrm dx\\[4pt]
& = \ln\left(2-2\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right) - 2
 - \cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi \ln\left(x^2-2x\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi+1\right)\bigg|_0^1\\[4pt]
& + 2\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi \arctan\dfrac{x-\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}{\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}\bigg|_0^1\\[4pt]
& = \ln\left(2-2\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right) - 2
 - \cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi \ln\left(2-2\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right)\\[4pt]
& + 2\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi 
\left(\arctan\dfrac{1-\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}{\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}
 + \arctan\dfrac{\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}{\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}\right)\\[4pt]
& = \ln\left(2-2\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right) - 2
 - \cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi \ln\left(2-2\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right)\\[4pt]
& + 2\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi
\arctan\dfrac{\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}
{\sin^2\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi - \left(1 - \cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right)\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi}\\[4pt]
& = \left(1-\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right)\ln\left(2-2\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right) - 2 + 2\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\arctan\cot\frac{2j+1}{4m}\pi,\\[4pt]
&T_j = \left(1-\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right)\ln\left(2-2\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right) - 2 + \dfrac{2(m-j)-1}{2m}\pi\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi.
\end{align}
Taking in account that
\begin{align}
&\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi 
= \Re \sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}e^{\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi i}
= \Re {\large \dfrac{1-e^{\pi i}}{1-e^{\frac\pi{m}i}}e^{\frac\pi{2m}i}}
=\Re\dfrac {i}{\sin\frac\pi{2m}} = 0,\\[4pt]
&\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi 
= \Im \sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}e^{\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi i}
=\Im\dfrac{i}{\sin\frac\pi{2m}} = \dfrac1{\sin\frac\pi{2m}},\\[4pt]
&\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\sin\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi
= \dfrac\pi{2\sin\frac\pi{2m}}
\end{align}
(see also [Wolfram Alpha calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%2F(2m)sum_(j%3D0,m-1)((2j%2B1)sin((2j%2B1)%2F(2m)pi))),

one can get
$$\boxed{I_{2m} = m(\ln2-2) + \dfrac\pi2\csc\frac\pi{2m}
 + \sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}\left(1\pm\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right)
\log\left(1\pm\cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi\right).}\tag6$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Closed form for the sum.}}$

From $(5)-(6)$ should
$$\color{green}{\boxed{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}\left(1\pm c_j\right)
\log\left(1\pm c_j\right)
= \dfrac1{2}\left(\psi_0\left(\dfrac{2m+1}{4m}\right) - \psi_0\left(\dfrac{1}{4m}\right)\right) - (m-1)\ln2 - \dfrac\pi2\csc\frac\pi{2m}
,}}\tag7$$
where 
$$c_j = \cos\frac{2j+1}{2m}\pi.$$

[Numeric calculations confirm](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(j%3D0,9)(0.5(1%2Bsgn(%7B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8%7D-j-0.1))(1-cos(((2j%2B1)%2F(%7B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8%7D))+pi%2F2))+ln(1-cos(((2j%2B1)%2F(%7B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8%7D))+pi%2F2)))) the expression $(6)$ for the both variants of the sign "$\pm$".

Also, numeric calculations [of the issue sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(j%3D0,9)(0.5(1%2Bsgn(%7B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8%7D-j-0.1))(1-cos(((2j%2B1)%2F(%7B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8%7D))+pi%2F2))+ln(1-cos(((2j%2B1)%2F(%7B1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8%7D))+pi%2F2)))) and [its closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B(polygamma(0,+1%2F2+%2B+1%2F(2%7B2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16%7D))+-+polygamma(0,+1%2F(2%7B2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16%7D)))%2F2.+-++(%7B2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16%7D%2F2+-1)*ln2+-+pi%2F2+csc(pi%2F%7B2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16%7D)%7D) $(7)$ confirm the correctness of the closed form for the both variants of the sign "$\pm$".

Comment: Very nice presentation, already before the alternate approach (+1).

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thanks, you are welcome!

Comment: @MarkusScheuer What about [this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739358/nested-root-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx/3311446#3311446)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer [Interesting integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705505/how-can-i-find-i-n-int-01-frac-x2n-ln-x1-x21x4ndx/3778181#3778181)

Comment: @YuriNegoetyanov: Very nice approach. Thanks for pointing at it. (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer [Integration in the elementary functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778656/prove-int-0-infty-frac-ln1x-arctan-sqrtx4x2-mathrmd/3809095#3809095)

Answer (score 2):

**I did it!**

I actually have no idea whether or not this works, but this is how I did it.

$n\in\Bbb N$

Define the sequence $\{r_k^{(n)}\}_{k=1}^{k=n}$ such that
$$x^n+1=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\big(x-r^{(n)}_{k}\big)$$
We then know that $$r_k^{(n)}=\exp\bigg[\frac{i\pi}{n}(2k-1)\bigg]$$
Then we define 
$$S_n=\{r_k^{(n)}:k\in[1,n]\cap\Bbb N\}$$
So we have that 
$$\frac1{x^n+1}=\prod_{r\in S_n}\frac1{x-r}=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{x-r_k^{(n)}}$$
Then we assume that we can write
$$\prod_{r\in S_n}\frac1{x-r}=\sum_{r\in S_n}\frac{b(r)}{x-r}$$
Multiplying both sides by $\prod_{a\in S_n}(x-a)$,
$$1=\sum_{r\in S_n}b(r)\prod_{a\in S_n\\ a\neq r}(x-a)$$
So for any $\omega\in S_n$,
$$1=b(\omega)\prod_{a\in S_n\\ a\neq \omega}(\omega-a)$$
$$b(\omega)=\prod_{a\in S_n\\ a\neq \omega}\frac1{\omega-a}$$
$$b(r_k^{(n)})=\prod_{p=1\\ p\neq k}^n\frac1{r_k^{(n)}-r_p^{(n)}}$$
So we know that 
$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b(r_k^{(n)})\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x-r_k^{(n)}}$$
$$I_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b(r_k^{(n)})\log\bigg|\frac{r_k^{(n)}-1}{r_k^{(n)}}\bigg|$$
$$I_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\bigg|\frac{r_k^{(n)}-1}{r_k^{(n)}}\bigg|\prod_{p=1\\ p\neq k}^n\frac1{r_k^{(n)}-r_p^{(n)}}$$
So we have
$$\int_0^1\log(1+x^n)\mathrm{d}x=\log2-n+n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\bigg|\frac{r_k^{(n)}-1}{r_k^{(n)}}\bigg|\prod_{p=1\\ p\neq k}^n\frac1{r_k^{(n)}-r_p^{(n)}}$$
along with a plethora of other identities...

Comment: Cheers @clathratus - I will have to have a look over in detail, but on the surface it looks good. Thanks heaps!

Comment: I say this not as a critique of your post, but of my own... do I have defend the set $r_j$ as having size $n$ ?? i.e. that the $c_j$ are distinct...

Comment: Well any polynomial with degree $n$ is going to have $n$ distinct roots, so it would make sense that $|S_n|=n$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another, quicker, method (I also don't know if this one works)

Using the same $r_k^{(n)}$ as last time, we apply the $\log\prod_{i}a_i=\sum_i\log a_i$ property to see that 
$$\log(1+x^n)=\log\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x-r_k^{(n)})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(x-r_k^{(n)})$$
So 
$$I_n=\int_0^1\log(1+x^n)\mathrm dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_0^1\log(x-r_k^{(n)})\mathrm dx$$
This last integral boils down to 
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\log(x-a)\mathrm dx=&a\log\frac{a}{1+a}+\log(1-a)-1\\
=&\log\frac{a^a(1-a)}{e(1+a)^a}
\end{align}$$
So 
$$I_n=\sum_{r\in S_n}\log\frac{r^r(1-r)}{e(1+r)^r}$$
And you know how I love product representations, so we again use $\log\prod_{i}a_i=\sum_i\log a_i$ to see that 
$$
I_n=\log\prod_{r\in S_n}\frac{r^r(1-r)}{e(1+r)^r}\\
\prod_{r\in S_n}\frac{r^r(1-r)}{(1+r)^r}=\exp(n+I_n)
$$
Which I just think is really neat.