# Integral involving complex exponential function

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-integration

I am trying to solve the following integral:$$\int_0^∞\frac{e^{-α(u+iπ/2)}\exp(te^{u+iπ/2})}{(u+iπ/2)^{β+1}}\,\mathrm du-\int_0^∞\frac{e^{-α(u-iπ/2)}\exp(te^{u-iπ/2})}{(u-iπ/2)^{β+1}}\,\mathrm du$$with $α,t>0$ and $\Re β>-1$.

I am not able to simplify. It seems that may be solve using complex analysis with Cauchy Theorem and a appropriate path.

**Note** that second integral is the conjugate of first one.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Latex note, use `\large` tag when you are building such edifices else it becomes quickly unreadable, especially the exponents.

Comment: What reason do you suspect a closed form? Having given a bounty, it seems this is the case.

Comment: Did I understand the first summand correctly? $\Large{\int_{-\frac{\pi i}{2}}^{\infty - \frac{\pi i}{2}} \frac{\exp(te^{u}-αu)}{(u)^{β+1}}\,\mathrm du}$ with $α,t>0$ and $\Re β>-1$.

Comment: >>second integral is the conjugate of first one. Is it really true? Could you explain that?

Comment: @Lada_Dudnikova You have wrote the second one integral.

Comment: >>second integral is the conjugate of first one. You can prove this using that $e^{-i\,x}$ is the conjugate of $e^{i\,x}$, writing $te^{u+iπ/2}$ as $t\,i\,e^{u}$ and $u+iπ/2$ in polar form.

Comment: What is the motivation for these integrals? Where do they come from? Why should we expect a nice answer? To see two feet standing alone in the desert can be a mystical experience. Second, if $\beta$ is a complex number, what branch of the complex exponent $z \mapsto z^{\beta+1}$ are you choosing in the denominator of the integrands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Contour integrals.}}$

Given integral can be presented in the form of
$$I = \int\limits_{C_{\Large_\rightarrow}} f(w)dw + \int\limits_{C_{\Large_\leftarrow}} f(w)dw,\tag1$$
where
$$f(w)=e^{-\alpha w} w^{-(\beta+1)} e^{\large te^{\Large w}},\tag2$$
contour $C_{\Large_\rightarrow}$ is line 
$$w=u+i\frac\pi2,\quad\text{where}\quad u = 0 \to\infty.$$
contour $C_{\Large_\leftarrow}$ is line 
$$w=u-i\frac\pi2,\quad\text{where}\quad u = \infty \to 0.$$
Let
$$C_{\Large_\uparrow}: w=0+iv,\quad\text{where}\quad v=-\frac\pi2\to \frac\pi2,$$
$$C_{\Large_\rightarrow}(R): z=u+i\frac\pi2,\quad\text{where}
\quad u = 0 \to \ln R,$$
$$C_{\Large_\downarrow}(R): z=\ln R+iv,\quad\text{where}
\quad v=\frac\pi2\to -\frac\pi2,$$
$$C_{\Large_\leftarrow}(R): z=u+i\frac\pi2,\quad\text{where}
\quad u = \ln R\to0.$$
then
$$C_{\Large_\rightarrow} = \lim\limits_{R\to\infty}C_{\Large_\rightarrow}(R),\quad
C_{\Large_\leftarrow} = \lim\limits_{R\to\infty}C_{\Large_\leftarrow}(R),\tag3$$
$$I = \lim\limits_{R\to\infty} I_R,\quad\text{where}
\quad I_R=\int\limits_{C_{\Large_\rightarrow}(R)} f(w)dw + \int\limits_{C_{\Large_\leftarrow}(R)} f(w)dw,\tag4$$

At the same time, the contour 
$$C = C_{\Large_\uparrow} + C_{\Large_\rightarrow}(R)+C_{\Large_\downarrow}(R)
 + C_{\Large_\leftarrow}(R)$$
is closed, and there are not special points inside.

Therefore,
$$\int\limits_{C_{\Large_\uparrow}} f(w)dw
 + \int\limits_{C_{\Large_\rightarrow}(R)} f(w)dw
 + \int\limits_{C_{\Large_\downarrow}(R)} f(w)dw
 + \int\limits_{C_{\Large_\leftarrow}(R)} f(w)dw = 0,$$
$$I_R = \int\limits_{C_{\Large_\rightarrow}(R)} f(w)dw
 + \int\limits_{C_{\Large \leftarrow}(R)} f(w)dw
= -\int\limits_{C_{\Large_\downarrow}(R)} f(w)dw
 - \int\limits_{C_{\Large \uparrow}} f(w)dw.\tag5$$

[image: Contours]

Substitution 
$$z=e^w,\quad dw = \dfrac{dz}z$$ 
provides the equalities
$$I_R = -\int\limits_{D_{\Large_\curvearrowright}(R)}g(z)\,dz
- \int\limits_{D_{\Large_\curvearrowleft}(R)}g(z)\,dz
= \int\limits_{D_{\Large_{\uparrow-}}(R)}g(z)\,dz
+ \int\limits_{D_{\Large_{\uparrow+}}}g(z)\,dz
 = -\int\limits_{E_{\Large_\curvearrowright}(R)}g(z)\,dz
- \int\limits_{E_{\Large_\curvearrowleft}}g(z)\,dz, \tag6$$
where
$$g(z) = z^{-(\alpha+1)}(\ln z)^{-(\beta+1)}e^{tz}\,dz,\tag7$$
$$D_{\Large_{\uparrow+}}: z=0+iy,\quad\text{where}\quad y=1\to R,$$
$$D_{\Large_\curvearrowright}(R): z=Re^{i\varphi},\quad\text{where}
\quad \varphi = \dfrac\pi2 \to \dfrac{3\pi}2,$$
$$D_{\Large_{\uparrow-}}(R): z=ye^{\Large \frac{3\pi}2i},\quad\text{where}
\quad y=R\to 1,$$
$$D_{\Large_\curvearrowleft}(R): z=e^{i\varphi},\quad\text{where}
\quad \varphi = \dfrac{3\pi}2\to\dfrac\pi2.$$
$$E_{\Large_\curvearrowleft}: z=e^{i\varphi},\quad\text{where}
\quad \varphi = \dfrac\pi2\to -\dfrac\pi2.$$
$$E_{\Large_{\uparrow-}}(R): z=ye^{\Large -\frac{\pi}2i},\quad\text{where}
\quad y=R\to 1,$$
$$E_{\Large_\curvearrowright}(R): z=Re^{i\varphi},\quad\text{where}
\quad \varphi = -\dfrac{\pi}2 \to \dfrac\pi2,$$

Easy to show that 
$$\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} \int\limits_{E_{\Large_\curvearrowright}}g(z)\,dz = 0.$$

Therefore,
$$I = -\int\limits_{E_{\Large_\curvearrowleft}}g(z)\,dz
 + \int\limits_{E_{\Large_{\uparrow-}}(\infty)}g(z)\,dz 
 - \int\limits_{D_{\Large_{\uparrow-}}(\infty)}g(z)\,dz,$$
$$ = i\int\limits_{\Large\frac\pi2}^{\Large\frac{3\pi}2}\,e^{-i\alpha\varphi}(i\varphi)^{-(\beta+1)}e^{\large te^{\Large i\varphi}}\, d\varphi
 +\int\limits_1^\infty \left(\left(\ln y+i{\small\frac32}\pi\right)^{-(\beta+1)} -  \left(\ln y-i\frac\pi2\right)^{-(\beta+1)}\right) y^{-\alpha}e^{-ity}\,dy.$$

Comment: Did you mean to write:  $z=e^w, \quad dw = \frac{dz}{z}$?

Comment: Very nice post! $\\\\$

Comment: @mjw Of course. Thanks!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you! Very hard and very nice task.

Comment: First, I want to give the thanks your effort, it's a hard work post. On the other hand, I've checked my integral with your expression using Wolfram Mathematica with the command NIntegrate and , unfortunately, I haven't obtain the same. For example, taking $a=b=t=1$ my integral value is $-0.132889 i$ and your integral value $-0.11136- 0.0617156 i$. You can check with other parameter's values and you will obtain diferent results.

Comment: taking $\alpha=\beta=t=1$

Comment: You say that $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} \int\limits_{E_{\Large_\curvearrowleft}}g(z)\,dz = 0$ but this integral not depeds on $R$. May be a mistake and you want change the role of $E↶$and $E↷(R)$ ?

Comment: Finally, I think that there are an error when you say $z=e^w$ and then $\ln(z)=w$: it's not true and probably this is the reason for our results are different (as mentioned before).

Comment: @popi Thank you for the support. The problem is in the phase term of logarithm, and it looks solvable. I'm trying to fix.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen What about [this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739358/nested-root-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx/3311446#3311446)

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov It's quite a good post. Well done.