# Integrating $\int_{3/2}^{8/3}\frac{\sqrt {x+\sqrt {x+\sqrt x}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{2}}}}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate the following? $$\int_{3/2}^{8/3}\frac{\sqrt {x+\sqrt {x+\sqrt x}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{2}}}}}dx$$ I am trying this question by writing the denominator as $\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{2}+x}}$ because $\sqrt{x^{2}}=x$. Now I am facing problem to simplify further. Please help me out. Also, I think we can't substitute $x=(tan\theta)^{4}$, because then the denominator will become very messy. So, please help me out to integrate the above expression.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe this has a closed-form solution? Or are you asking for numerical integration?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. _Wolfram Alpha_ [doesn't find](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sqrt%28x%2Bsqrt%28x%2Bsqrt%28x%29%29%29%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2%2Bsqrt%28x%5E2%2Bx%29%29+from+3%2F2+to+8%2F3&dataset=) a closed form.

Comment: Note that the simpler integral (without the denominator) is already very [tricky](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796982/integrating-int-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-dx).

Comment: Those limits of integration seem suspicious. There may be a way to do the integral without finding its antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

On yesterday, we had a much simpler problem (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796982/integrating-int-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-dx/4797027#4797027)) for which @Mariusz Iwaniuk gave the solution (which is a monster).

For your case, if you plot the integrand for the range of interest, you should notice that it is pretty close to a straight line.

So, write
$$\frac{\sqrt {x+\sqrt {x+\sqrt x}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{2}+\sqrt{x^{2}}}}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, (x-2)^n$$ I chose $2$ because $\frac 12\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{8}{3}\right)=2+\frac 1{12}$.

The coefficients are really ugly but the result will be
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, \frac{2^{n+2}\times 3^{-n}+(-1)^ n\, 3\times 2^{-n}}{6 (n+1)}$$

Computing the partial sums
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \sum_{n=0}^p \\
 0 & 0.901131 \\
 1 & 0.885235 \\
 2 & 0.891661 \\
 3 & 0.891215 \\
 4 & 0.891337 \\
 5 & 0.891325 \\
 6 & 0.891327 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$